# MySQL select query with case then and count

Tags: mysql

I have two tables naming `campaigns` and `coupons` with the following structure

**Campaigns**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Campaign 1 |
| 2 | Multiple Coupon Campaign |

**Coupons**

| id | campaign_id | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FREDEL |
| 2 | 2 | 123-xyz-coupon |
| 3 | 2 | xyw92b-cou |

I am trying to get result data set like this

| id | name | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Campaign 1 | FREDEL |
| 2 | Multiple Coupon Campaign | MULTIPLE |

Basically, if a campaign has multiple coupons, it should return `MULTIPLE` in the `reference` column, otherwise the coupon code itself.

I've tried something like this

```
select *, (select CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) from coupons as temp where temp.id=coupons.id)>1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE code END AS reference FROM coupons where coupons.campaign_id=campaigns.id limit 1) as reference from campaigns
```

but the result is not as expected and it shows the first coupon code of both campaigns instead of `MULTIPLE` for the second one.

Tried the below query as well

```
select *, (select CASE WHEN count(*)>1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE coupons.code END FROM coupons where coupons.campaign_id=campaigns.id) as reference from campaigns
```

and it throws

> In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db.coupons.code'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

**NOTE:** I am looking for a sub-query on select and to avoid join clause

Thank you

Comment: Writing it with a sub-query avoids typing the keyword `JOIN`, but when the plan is generated, it will still be a join.

Comment: @MatBailie That I didn't know. Do you have any reference for me to read? Thank you

Comment: *NOTE: I am looking for a sub-query on select and to avoid join clause* What is the source of this restriction?

Comment: Start by researching `explain plan`, and/or `declarative languages`.

Comment: @Akina Laravel ORM. If I could have sub-query, then I can use it as a scope as explained in here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes. This allows me to right the query to fetch the reference once and just call `reference()` whenever it's needed. I think, I can use your answer as a subquery and extract the result to use as a column. Double work, but that should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
name,
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN
            'MULTIPLE'
        ELSE
            MIN(code)
        END AS reference
    FROM
        coupons
    WHERE
        coupons.campaign_id = campaigns.id
    GROUP BY
        campaign_id) AS reference
FROM
    campaigns
```

Comment: This is more like what I was looking for. The sub-query is simple and can easily go in the local scope of Laravel Eloquent ORM. Using `min()` avoided the `GROUP BY` clause exception I had. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```sql
SELECT Campaigns.id,
       Campaigns.name,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1
            THEN MAX(Coupons.code)
            ELSE 'MULTIPLE'
            END reference
FROM Campaigns
JOIN Coupons ON Coupons.campaign_id = Campaigns.id
GROUP BY Campaigns.id, Campaigns.name
```

> I was looking for a sub-query select version. – Kalesh Kaladharan

```sql
SELECT Campaigns.id,
       Campaigns.name,
       CASE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM Coupons 
              WHERE Coupons.campaign_id = Campaigns.id ) 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'NONE'
            WHEN 1 THEN ( SELECT Coupons.code
                          FROM Coupons 
                          WHERE Coupons.campaign_id = Campaigns.id )
            ELSE 'MULTIPLE'
            END reference
FROM Campaigns
-- HAVING reference <> 'NONE'
```

Comment: This works! But I was looking for a sub-query select version. Actually forgot to mention that on the question. I'll update the question. Thank you.